# Basic css question

Tags: html, css

please see http://jsfiddle.net/8mmbA/1/

How to make a separation between coordinate and dimension div , say 10 px. I tried margin and padding. For dimension the margin adds from coordinate 0 (left most part in the page), not from the previous div.

thanks.
bsr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add float:left to your dimension:

`#location #dimension{float:left; margin-left:10px;}`

Comment: Keith.. thanks for the answer..may i ask u for a clarification, I thought float:left would carry over from the previous div. I read the float setting inherit till you explicitly clear it .. thanks again

Comment: Think of float as you would think of a newspaper image having text wrap around it.  If you only float the first div, the 2nd div will still exist at the upper-left coordinate, but its contents will wrap around the first.  You need to float both in order for them to respect each others' margins/padding.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/8mmbA/10/

Set it to `display:block` else margins won't trigger.

Comment: thanks.. but, I don't think ur conclusion was right.. see I updated your answer http://jsfiddle.net/8mmbA/13/ . margin-right on the left div was the real cause

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding-right: 10px; to the Coordinate div.

Answer (score 0):

`margin-right` on the left div

http://jsfiddle.net/8mmbA/9/